# Retrieve username object from pointer - Parse, swift

Tags: pointers, swift, parse-platform, friend

I am working on an app with a Parse backend that will allow people to send friends invites and to respond to them. I currently have a Parse class called Friendship with a fromUser, toUser and status objet. I have my app setup so you're now able to send someone an invite. But, I don't know how to display these requests is the app. This is because when I query the fromUser object of a request, I get the object id etc. instead. How can I display these users usernames?

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation is extremely helpful:
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS

And no doubt you are dealing with **Relations**:
https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide

So, if I understand properly, you probably go check `includeKey`. That will help you query all the data instead of just returning objectId, createdDate and updateDate.

Comment: nailed it. I would add that you should make sure you've set the fields for `toUser` and `forUser` to be Pointers, etc. if you're still running into issues